# ¿Cómo puedo restar un lista de listas?

Tags: python, lista

Quiesiera restar los valores de una lista de listas.

```
lista=[[x1,x2,x3,x4],[x1,x2,x3,x4],[x1,x2,x3,x4],[x1,x2,x3,x4],[x1,x2,x3,x4]]
```

Que el primer x1 se reste con todos los demas y asi teniendo como resultado:

```
lista=[[x1-x1-x1-x1,x2-x2-x2-x2,x3-x3-x3-x3,x4-x4-x4-x4]]
```

¿Alguien sabria como ayudarme? necesitaria que sirva sin importar la cantidad de valores.

El codigo es largo pero lo que hice fue hacer la lista de esta manera:

```
lista=[]
1=[x,x,x,x]
2=[x,x,x,x]
lista.append(1)
lista.apepen(2)
```

Esto en un script largo pero solo tengo problemas porque tengo una lista con muchas (filas seria para mi) que quisiera que se restaran por columnas de arriba a abajo.

Comment: Podrías poner el código que haz hecho para crear la resta?

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a [es.so], te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. ¿Qué has intentado hacer hasta el momento? Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que los usuarios publiquen sus preguntas junto con lo que han intentado, de esa forma se demuestra que has hecho un esfuerzo por resolver tu pregunta/problema, de lo contrario probablemente la pregunta termine cerrada y/o votada negativamente. Lectura recomendada: [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: ¿Todas las sublistas tienen siempre 4 elementos? ¿O por lo menos siempre es el mismo número de elementos para todas las sublistas?

Comment: No sabía que podías llamar variables como números

Comment: Buen día @NicolasCesarini, si alguna respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

**Nota:** Algo que no menciona tu pregunta es si todas las sublistas tienen siempre la misma cantidad de elementos (En tu ejemplo son 4), en esta respuesta considero que todas las sublistas son del mismo tamaño.

Utilizando la siguiente lista como ejemplo:

```
lista = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16],[17,18,19,20]]
```

Primero reorganizamos las sublistas para obtener "grupos" de acuerdo al índice de los elementos

```
nueva_lista = [[e[i] for e in lista] for i in range(4)]
```

En este caso `range(4)` es porque el tamaño de las sublistas es de 4 elementos. Al imprimir `nueva_lista` obtenemos lo siguiente:

```
[[1, 5, 9, 13, 17], [2, 6, 10, 14, 18], [3, 7, 11, 15, 19], [4, 8, 12, 16, 20]]
```

Y para obtener la resta de cada sublista primero utilizamos el primer elemento y restamos la sumatoria de todos los elementos siguientes

```
resultado = [e[0] - sum(e[1:]) for e in nueva_lista]
```

Al imprimir `resultado` obtenemos lo siguiente:

```
[-43, -46, -49, -52]
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
lista = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16],[17,18,19,20]]

nueva_lista = [[e[i] for e in lista] for i in range(4)]
resultado = [e[0] - sum(e[1:]) for e in nueva_lista]
print(resultado)
```

O podría hacerse en una sola línea:

```
lista = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16],[17,18,19,20]]

print([x[0] - sum(x[1:]) for i in range(4) for x in [[e[i] for e in lista]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Según mi entendimiento de la pregunta quieres una solución robusta para restar listas sin importar el tamaño de las sublistas, ya vi que alguien ya contesto como hacer eso en el ámbito del ejemplo que diste pero quería proveer una solución mas robusta.

```
def restar_lista(lista: list):
    """
    Resta los valores de una lista en cual:
        [5,2,1] -> 2 
    Si la lista esta bacia regresa 0 
    """
    if not lista:
        return 0
    elif len(lista) == 1:
        return lista[0]
    return lista[0] - sum(lista[1:])

def organizar_los_valores_a_sus_listas_adecuadas(lista_de_listas: list) -> list:
    """
    Organiza la lista de lista por el indice de cada lista sin importar si los indices son difrenetes. 
    Asi que:
        [1,2,3][1,2,3][1,2,3,4] -> [1,1,1][2,2,2][3,3,3][4]
    """
    tamano_de_la_lista_mas_grande: int = max([len(i) for i in lista_de_listas])
    nueva_lista = []
    
    for indice in range(tamano_de_la_lista_mas_grande):
        sublista = []
        
        for lista in lista_de_listas:
            try:
                sublista.append(lista[indice])
            except IndexError:
                pass
                
        nueva_lista.append(sublista)

    return nueva_lista
    

def solucion(tu_lista: list):
    lista_organizada = organizar_los_valores_a_sus_listas_adecuadas(tu_lista)
    lista_restada = [restar_lista(i) for i in lista_organizada]
    return lista_restada
```

Con esto vamos a decir que le pones mi ejemplo ya mencionado de `[[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3,4]]`. Si le pones eso a la función solución esto pasará:

1. `lista organizada = [[1,1,1,1], [2,2,2,2], [3,3,3,3], [4]]`
2. Para cada lista en las listas organizadas crear una lista aplicando la función `restar_lista` en lugar de el valor original. Básicamente de 1 recibes `[-2, -4, -6, 4]`

Si tiene cualquier pregunta sobre como sirve esto deja un comentario bajo esta respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Perdon. Lo solucione mirando de una manera que no se si es la correcta pero funciono.
Asi que ya esta resuelto el problema.
Use la funcion sum() junto con zip(*lista)
la lista hice que cada valor que se le agregaba tenga un -(numero) para que haga la resta y funciono. Igualmente gracias por las respuestas. Las voy a revisar para ver si me conviene hacerlas de otra manera

```
resultado_int=[sum(l) for l in zip(*datos_calculo_total)]
```

Comment: No olvides aceptar la respuesta que te ha sido más útil.